# Unable to install the JSON extension in PHP's docker image

Tags: php, json, docker, php-8

I recently started to upgrade my projects from PHP 7.4 to 8.0, and I'm currently trying to rebuild all my Docker images to PHP 8.0 as well so both my images and my environment are coherent.

Before this upgrade, I was using `php:7.4`, and inside my Dockerfile, I had this line for the extensions installation:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql json
```

Today, the same command works *EXCEPT* for JSON, where I get the following error:

```
Installing shared extensions:     /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20200930/
cp: cannot stat 'modules/*': No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:87: install-modules] Error 1
```

I can't find anyone else with this problem on Stack Overflow or the web in general, so... Has the name changed, or is it not required anymore? Or is it even normal?

Comment: When you say the same command works except for JSON, do you mean that it works when you just run `RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It runs smoothly but the moment I try to do the same with json, I get the error.

Comment: Oh so that must be the reason why I can't install it... because it's already installed.

Comment: Yes it's working, I just tried to use `json_decode` and `json_encode`, my IDE asked me to add "ext-json" in the composer.json file, but that excepted, it works fine

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In PHP 8 the [JSON extension was made "always available"](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/always_enable_json) so there isn't a need to manually install it anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I was scratching my head wondering why on the PHP 8.2 docker image it was failing.